# Either neither or none

Tags: usage

In the following sentence whether **neither** or **none** should be used?

> On account of shortage of time none of them can finish their work.

> On account of shortage of time neither of them can finish his work.

What is the difference in the above two sentences?

Comment: If there are two people, neither can finish his or her work, if more than two, or if number is unknown, none can finish their work.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey both the sentences given in OP grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, both are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither means 'not one or the other of two', and a singular verb must follow.

None means 'not one of an unspecified number' and can be followed by a singular or plural verb. In either case, it may be desired to use a non-gender pronoun ('their') unless it is definitely known that all possible persons being considered are of the same gender.

If there are two people, neither can finish his or her work. If more than two, or if number is unknown, none can finish their work.